# How to add a directory to svn v1.6 repo without adding any contents

Tags: svn

```
parentdir
    childdir001
    ...
    childdir999
```

I have a parent directory with a bazillion directories in it. The directory and its contents are new and have not yet been added to the svn v1.6 repo.

How do I add `parentdir` to the svn repo, without adding any of its contents to the repo?

EDIT: In summary, I want to do

`svn add-this-but-nothing-inside-of-it parentdir`.

Comment: I do not want to permanently ignore the contents of `parentdir`. I just want to put it in the repo, so I can then immediately add `childdir001`. When I try to add `childdir001`, I get an error saying that a node for `parentdir` cannot be found (because I haven't added `parentdir` to the repo yet.

Comment: And when I try `svn mkdir parentdir`, I get the error cannot make this because it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

According to the SVN documentation found [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html), you should be able to execute the following command:

```
svd add <directoryYouWantToAdd> --depth empty
```

As far as I know, this option should be available from SVN 1.5+.